# How to meassure a high frequency dirty current?

Tags: current-measurement

I'm interested in a way to accurately (about 10 % accuracy) meassure a sinusoidal current that has a 25 kHz frequency and has A LOT of higher harmonics. Voltage is unknown but is supposed to be around 300 V.

What instrument can I use?

Comment: Do you want to just measure the 25kHz part or the harmonics too? For the earlier just have a bandpass filter, assume perfect sine and multipl the rms out of the avg.

Comment: Is this a rectified current waveform, with most energy in the 2nd harmonic?

Comment: I want to meassure all of the current and calculate the mean value so I can know for what average current I can start dimensioning a coil. Right now I'm only interested in meassuring the current that gets generated inside a coil of a regular induction hob.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Adjusted answer to allow measurement of current.

Place a current sampling device in series with the load such as a low value shunt resistor. This will provide a known current to voltage transformation.

A spectrum analyzer is a good choice for this type of application. You will be able to clearly measure the level of the fundamental signal and observe the level of the harmonics. Make certain to pick a spectrum analyzer with a sufficiently low frequency range.

You may find a sound card spectrum analyzer that has a high enough range to catch the fundamental frequency. Look for sound card FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) software/hardware and check its high frequency limit.

Take care to account for the common mode voltage between the DUT and the measurement instrument.

Comment: The frequency is known. I'm interested in the average or effective current.

Comment: I will edit my answer to help with this.